# Is it possible to use newer APIs in android apps that support older OS?

Tags: android

Say that you are building an app that supports versions 5 up to 9 but want to use an API that is not supported in versions older than Android 6. Is there a workaround to make it work on Android 5 devices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case of first party libraries, it is almost always the case that the Android team releases a support library that works in older versions when possible. So if there is an API that is not supported there must be something that really can't be done.

In case of third party libraries you should have a look into why it's not supported as it might just be the author's preference, and there could be chance that you can fork and tweak the code to work for older APIs (With consideration of licenses of course). The reason why it doesn't support older API's might not be a crux to your needs, so dive into that code!